# server side render fails after page refresh

Tags: reactjs, dom, import, require

I have the following React component, from which I am almost sure my error is comming from :

```
function Gallery(props) {
const urlArray = props.urlArray
        
const SlideShow = typeof window !== 'undefined' ? require('react-image-show').default : undefined               
        

return (
    <div>
        { 
            <SlideShow />
        
        }
    </div>
  )
}

export default Gallery
```

Now when I enter my website, I enter the page that renders this component, everything works fine, but if I refresh the page I get

```
Error: Minified React error #130;
```

which translates to

```
Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined.
```

It looks like the `const SlideShow` is set to undefined after refresh.

Now I know there are many questions on this topic, but most are about bad import syntax, which is not the case here, because my component renders corectly, only after refresh it crashes.
Any idea why is this happening and how can I fix it ?